# Give rating then review, or review than give rating?

Tags: rating, movie, recommendation-engine, review, rs

I want to build a Recommender System themed movie recommendations (refer to study P. Massa and P.Avesani). I have my own opinion on this, that the user must give ratings first before going to the review page. In other words, users can only give a review after giving the rating.

However, there is also review can change one's perspective on a movie, so the user can review first and then give a rating.

But I had to choose one, so I'm confused. 
I want to use both methods. But actually desired is a review of the movie can only be raised when the movie has been given a rating.

I would be very grateful if anyone can provide suggestions and opinions here for me.
Which is better, give rate then review or the review first and then give ratings?
Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @Smandoli I'm so sorry, but I will use to determine the architecture of the system to be built..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been an active user of the biggest movie site there is for a couple of years now, so this question applies to me very well.

I have seen a ton of reviews without ratings over these few year, but I don't feel allowing submitting such reviews is a good approach. For me, as a person who would like to compare opinions with other members of a site, it is easier to look at the rating before I start to read the review in detail, especially if it's a long one. For example, if I love a movie and I spot that someone has given it a low rating and has essentially written an essay on it, I'm more than happy to give it a look. On the other hand, if such an essay has no rating, I'll just skip it.

From a perspective of a person who rates movies, there are some films that I don't want to give a specific rating to instantly, because I have to sleep over it. You could argue that it's plausible to write a review and give an appropriate rating afterwards, but I think that unless you are sure of the score you're going to give to a certain film, you cannot write a truly satisfying review.

All in all, ratings first.

P.S. Too bad it's not an actual programming question...

Comment: I'm so sorry for my question. But, thanks, very helpfull! I got the spirit to continue my final project after knowing.